# Find all positive integers x such that x(x + 180) is a square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x^2 + 180x = k^2$

$k^2 - x^2 = 180x$

$(k+x)(k-x) = 180x$

Now i wrote $180x$ as $1(180x) , (2)(90x) , \dots , (180)(x)$ and i compared these values with $(k+x)(k-x)$ and found $12,60$ to be the only 2 integers , are there more ?
Also if you have a better method please share.

Comment: Someone please edit the question for exponents !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG $k\ge0\implies x+90+k>x+90-k$

$\implies(x+90+k)^2>(x+90-k)(x+90+k)=8100$

$\implies(x+90+k)>\sqrt{8100}=90\ \ \ \ (1)$

As $x+90+k+x+90-k=2(x+90)$ is even, $x+90+k,x+90-k$ have the same parity

As $(x+90-k)(x+90+k)=8100$  is even

$$\dfrac{x+90-k}2\cdot\dfrac{x+90+k}2=2025$$

By $(1),\dfrac{x+90+k}2>45$ and must divide $2025$  so, must belong to $\in[75, 81, 135, 225, 405, 675, 2025]$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Rewrite it as $(x + 90 + k)(x + 90 - k) = 8100$. Now you can factorize $8100$.

Comment: Thanks I completely forgot about completion of square method 

Comment: I have a doubt : 8100 has 45 divisors , am i supposed to check x for all 45 ?

Comment: Partly yes and partly no. Note that both factors have the same parity, and hence they must be both even. This saves you some work, but still there are many to check, as the number $180$ is moderately big (and has quite a lot of factors).

Comment: Thanks this will save me some time 